can I define a globally unique complex SCIM attribute?
I want work email attribute to be globally unique. How do I define that in schema definition?
{
        "name" : "emails",
        "type" : "complex",
        "multiValued" : true,
        "description" : "...",
        "required" : true,
        "subAttributes" : [
          {
            "name" : "value",
            "type" : "string",
            "multiValued" : false,
            "description" : "...",
            "required" : true,
            "caseExact" : false,
            "mutability" : "readWrite",
            "returned" : "default",
            "uniqueness" : "global" <-- applicable only if type is 'work'
          },
...


You can't. There are limitations to what can be represented in the SCIM JSON schema format, one of which has to do with conditional properties like this - "the value is unique IF type is work".
The best you can do is to mention it in your documentation and/or in the "Description" attribute on the schema object for "emails".
